# I can not log into another Linux machine

Tags: ssh

I can not log into another Linux box and I have tried using this form ssh my-user-name@my-server-ip but it returns the error after 3 tries to permission denied (publickey,password)

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/778413/can-not-resolve-aliases-for-ssh)? I think could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is fine, I would recommend to check the password since looks like it is wrong.