# Can not resolve aliases for ssh

Tags: ssh, alias

Here is my problem:

- I got two machines in the same network 192.168.122.0/24

my /etc/hosts :

```
192.168.122.100  toto
192.168.122.110  tata
```

if I type : `ssh toto`:

```
root@toto's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).`
```

but If I type `ssh toto@192.168.122.100` it works..

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You must specify the remote user, otherwise it will use the user that you are logged into locally.

For example:

```
ssh username@host
```

So, in your case you would use:

```
ssh toto@toto
```

Comment: If you do not specify a User (`user@host`), you will use the user specified within your `~/.ssh/config` file, or whichever user you are on the current machine (in this case, you're root on the local machine when ssh'ing).

Answer (score 1):

First, did you check these directives on /etc/ssh/sshd_config (toto host)?

```
AllowUsers root toto
PermitRootLogin yes
```

If it is a production environment, I strongly suggest set these directives at this way:

```
AllowUsers toto
Port 2233
PermitRootLogin no
```

**Avoid root access and design other port than 22. It's safer.**

If you want to access local network hosts without password prompt, just follow these steps bellow (let's suppose totXX=host client, totYY=host server ssh):

1. Create the same user in all machines (Ex: toto) with the same
   password;
2. Generate the public key on totXX

   ```
   # may output a message like this:
   toto@totXX:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa 
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.   
   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/toto/.ssh/id_rsa):  
   Created directory '/home/toto/.ssh'.  
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):  
   Enter same passphrase again:  
   Your identification has been saved in /home/toto/.ssh/id_rsa. 
   Your public key has been saved in /home/toto/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. 
   The key fingerprint is:
   3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 toto@totXX
   ```
3. Create ~/.ssh directory on totYY

   ```
   toto@totXX:~> ssh toto@totYY mkdir -p .ssh
   toto@totYY password:
   ```
4. Put totXX public key on totYY:

   ```
   toto@totXX:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh toto@totoYY 'cat >>  ssh/authorized_keys'  
   toto@totoYY password:
   ```
5. Restart ssh service on totYY:

   ```
   toto@totXX:~> sudo service ssh restart
   ```
6. If everything is ok, the password won't be requested on ssh access.

   ```
   toto@totoXX:~> ssh toto@totoYY  
   toto@totYY:~>
   ```